# Not returning any data after promise in Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi I'm currently working on a `Ionic` application that has to show to the user some data into a `Form Group` after getting it with a SOAP ReadData.

I'm calling my function and then I display the data into the form, the only problem is that the form is not showing.

```
constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  public navParams: NavParams,
  private privacyProvider: PrivacyProvider,
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {

  this.myParam = navParams.get('myParam');

  console.log(this.myParam);

  this.getAnagrafica().then(() => {
    console.log(this.iobAnagrafica);
    debugger;
    this.formAnagrafica = this.formBuilder.group({
      ID_INSTALLATO: new 
 FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_installato),
      ID_ANAGRAFICA: new FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_anag),
      ID_PRODUTTORE: new 
 FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_produttore),
      ID_GRUPPO: new FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_gruppo),
      ID_INSTALLATORE: new 
 FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_installatore)
      });
   });

 }

 getAnagrafica(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{


this.privacyProvider.getIOBAnagrafica(this.myParam).subscribe((data)=> {
   if (data) {
     this.iobAnagrafica = data;
     resolve(true);
   } else {
      reject();
   }
 })
});
}
```

How can I solve this error?
This is my HTML:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list *ngIf="formLoaded">
<form [formGroup]="formAnagrafica">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>ID INSTALLATO</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="ID_INSTALLATO" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>ID ANAGRAFICA</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="ID_ANAGRAFICA" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>ID PRODUTTORE</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="ID_PRODUTTORE" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>ID GRUPPO</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="ID_GRUPPO" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>ID INSTALLATORE</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="ID_INSTALLATORE" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

Comment: What does your console.log(this.iobAnagrafica); return ? Does your promise correctly resolve ?

Comment: yes promise correctly resolve.

Comment: Could we also have your template code ?

Comment: what you mean for template code?

Comment: Your .html file

Comment: @rguerin added html

Answer (score 0):

It seems you never set your `formLoaded` flag to true.

Try this :

```
this.getAnagrafica().then(() => {
    console.log(this.iobAnagrafica);
    debugger;
    this.formAnagrafica = this.formBuilder.group({
      ID_INSTALLATO: new 
 FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_installato),
      ID_ANAGRAFICA: new FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_anag),
      ID_PRODUTTORE: new 
 FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_produttore),
      ID_GRUPPO: new FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_gruppo),
      ID_INSTALLATORE: new 
 FormControl(this.iobAnagrafica.id_installatore)
      });

      this.formLoaded = true;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **ngModel** in your case: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/forms/
declare a variable in your ts

```
public callBack;
constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  public navParams: NavParams,
  private privacyProvider: PrivacyProvider,
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {

  this.myParam = navParams.get('myParam');

  console.log(this.myParam);

  this.getAnagrafica().then((chart) => {
    this.callBack = chart;
 }
...
```

after that, it should display into fields and you can use the **callBack** variable for ngIf too

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list *ngIf="callBack">
<form [formGroup]="formAnagrafica">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>ID INSTALLATO</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="callBack.id_installato" formControlName="ID_ANAGRAFICA" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
...
```